# exception emyxerror in module mysql query browser.exe at 0010F992

Tags: mysql

Whenever I try to open Mysql Query Browser, that error appears. What should I do?

[exception emyxerror in module mysql query browser.exe at 0010F992 / Error while loading stored connections.Error Numver 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBqwt.png)

Mysql query browser wanted to be executed. However, the error appeared and there was no solution found on the Internet.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling the browser and see if that helps.  And another thing is if you are working with MySQL .. you will really like MySQL Workbench as an alternative way to view and modify database information.

Comment: If that interests you here is a direct link to a download to Workbench
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/